# Como obter o último segmento do path?

Tags: regex, htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

```
URLs de exemplo:
content/edit
content/edit/
content/edit?q=
content/edit/?q=
```

Eu tentei fazer o código mas sempre falha quando a url não possui "/" ou "?" e se tiver "/?" no final. O código que fiz foi:

```
.*\/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)[\/\?].*
```

Que pega o valor "edit".

Comment: Quais são os resultados esperados? Em todos a palavra `edit` deverá ser retornada ou no último a parte `?q=` também deverá estar presente no retorno?

Comment: na vdd somente o edit e ignorar as variaveis

Comment: Então não é necessariamente entre as últimas ocorrências de `/`, mas sim sempre o último segmento do *path*?

Comment: Isto ai! mas só preciso da ultima palavra, no caso edit, que podera ser qualquer outra.

Comment: É que a cada edição a pergunta fica mais confusa. Em uma URL `edit?q=teste`, a última palavra seria `teste`, mas o que você precisa é `edit`, correto? Se sim, use a expressão *último segmento do path*, para não gerar qualquer confusão.

Comment: Vc está certo, fiz as alterações

Comment: Posta exatamente como esta o seu .htaccess todo, pois multiplos rewrites podem conflitar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solução mais simples é utilizando PHP, como apresentado em outras respostas, mas se desejar apenas a expressão regular para utilizar junto ao arquivo `.htaccess`, veja a solução abaixo.

Para responder isso, precisamos primeiro entender a estrutura da uma URI:

```
  foo://example.com:8042/over/there;param=value;p2;p3?name=ferret#nose
  \_/   \______________/\_________/ \_______________/ \_________/ \__/
   |           |            |              |              |         |
scheme     authority       path          params         query   fragment
```

Podemos perceber que após o `path` podem existir os valores de `param`, `query` e `fragment`. Começamos então analisando apenas o `path`:

Para obter o último segmento do *path*, utilizamos a expressão regular:

```
\/?([a-zA-Z0-9_\-+]+)\/?$
```

Isto é, o valor pode iniciar com uma barra, seguida de uma sequência não nula de letras, números ou `_`, `-` e `+` (pode alterar livremente essa parte), seguida ou não de uma barra, terminando o valor. Desta forma, as seguintes URLs abaixo serão devidamente analisadas:

```
edit
/edit
/edit/
/content/edit
/content/edit/
```

> Veja funcionando no [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/XoX4ii/1).

Agora, devemos adicionar à expressão a parte que analisará a possível existência do *params* na URL. Para simplificar, como não é de nosso interesse saber quais são os parâmetros do *path*, vamos considerar como parâmetro qualquer sequência de caracteres diferente de `/` que segue o caractere `;`. Tanto o caractere quando a sequência serão opcionais, então a expressão regular passa a ser:

```
\/?([a-zA-Z0-9_\-+]+)\/?(?:\;[^\/]*)?$
```

Assim, tanto as URLs acima como as abaixo funcionarão:

```
edit
/edit
/edit/
/content/edit
/content/edit/
/content/edit;param=foo
/content;param=foo/edit/
```

> Veja funcionando no [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rRFtHN/1).

A mesma lógica iremos aplicar para a *query* da URL, sendo definida como qualquer sequência de caracteres que segue o caractere `?`. Assim, a expressão regular passa a ser:

```
\/?([a-zA-Z0-9_\-+]+)\/?(?:\;[^\/]*)?(?:\?.*)?$
```

Assim, as todas as URLs abaixo irão funcionar:

```
edit
/edit
/edit/
/content/edit
/content/edit/
/content/edit;param=foo
/content;param=foo/edit/
/content/edit?q=foo
/content/edit/?q=foo
```

> Veja funcionando no [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/WmoTlU/1).

Para completar, falta analisar a parte do *fragment* da URL, sendo definido como qualquer sequência de caracteres que segue o caractere `#`.

```
\/?([a-zA-Z0-9_\-+]+)\/?(?:\;[^\/]*)?(?:\?.*)?(?:\#.*)?$
```

Funcionando, assim, para todas as variações de URL possíveis:

```
edit
/edit
/edit/
/content/edit
/content/edit/
/content/edit;param=foo
/content;param=foo/edit/
/content/edit?q=foo
/content/edit/?q=foo
/content/edit#foo
/content/edit/#foo
```

Em todas, o único grupo capturado será `edit`.

> Veja funcionando no [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/g2hcQo/1).

A mesma expressão pode ser simplificada para:

```
\/?([\w+-]+)\/?(?|\;[^\/]*|[?#].*)?$
```

Colaboração de [Guilherme Lautert](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/238290/como-obter-o-%c3%baltimo-segmento-do-path/238371?noredirect=1#comment488589_238371).

> Veja funcionando no [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/g2hcQo/2).

Comment: Dava para reduzia a regex, fora isso muito bom e bem explicado +1.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert o que sugere?

Comment: Assim ja reduz um pouco https://regex101.com/r/g2hcQo/2

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert realmente ficou bem mais simples. Obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Uma maneira bem simples, sem usar expressão regular:

```php
//Obtenha a URL sem as variáveis
$url = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'];

//exploda 
$array_url = explode('/',$url);

//Caso a URL termine com /, a última posição do array estará em branco, então contorne isso
$array_url=array_filter($array_url);

//A última posição do array equivale à ultima palavra.
$palavra = array_pop($array_url);
```

Comment: Apesar da parte do array estar boa na resposta, no entanto `REDIRECT_URL` pode variar e depende muito da configuração do Apache, geralmente vai existir na maior parte dos servidores, mas em questões de fastgci e fpm isso pode ser algo que varia muito. Como disse, a resposta não é ruim, o problema é que o script esta confiando em uma variavel que realmente pode "variar" em diferentes servidores. O melhor seria usar algo como `PHP_SELF`+`parse_url(..., PHP_URL_PATH)`. Entenda como sugestão, pode efetuar seus testes para confirmar.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que este regex resolve o seu problema:

```
(\/\w+\/\w+)((\/?$)|(\?.+$))
```

Criei um teste no link abaixo:

https://regex101.com/r/b48kWg/1

O conteúdo que você precisa está no grupo 1 (verde)

Comment: e se eu tiver somente "content/edit" ou "content/edit?q=123321&outroparametro=432" sem www e etc e queria pegar somente a palavra edit ?

Comment: Não tem problema, porque a regra é o "termina com". Eu adicionei o www... porque acreditei se tratar de uma URL completa, mas vai funcionar do mesmo jeito.

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar `preg_split()` para capturar todos os valores entre as barras e chamar `array_reverse()` para inverter a ordem dos elementos, jogando o último como primeiro. `preg_match()` verifica se o elmento atual começa com alguma letra caso contrário passa para o próximo elemento isso trata o caso `?Q=abc`

```
function ultimaParteURL($url){
    $segmentos = array_reverse(preg_split('#/#', $url , null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
    foreach ($segmentos as $item){
        if(preg_match('#^[A-Z]#i', $item)) return $item; 
    }
}

echo ultimaParteURL('content/edit/?Q=abc') .'<br>';
echo ultimaParteURL('content/edit/') .'<br>';
echo ultimaParteURL('content/edit&abc=12015') .'<br>';
```

Exemplo:

```
Array
(
    [0] => content
    [1] => edit?q=
)
```

Após a chamada de `array_reverse()` vira:

```
Array
(
    [0] => edit?q=
    [1] => content
)
```